# How can I make commit tree above origin/master into a single, linear commit to prepare for push?

Tags: git, merge, rebase

After messing around with rebase for a while trying to get this to work, I turned my commit history into a weird looking tree as you can see below.  Instead, I'm looking to have everything above origin/master combined into a single, neat, linear commit to prepare it for pushing remotely.

```
*   7e6d942 (HEAD, master) Merge branch 'feature'
|\
| * 426933d (feature) add majority of code
* |   0951849 Merge feature branch
|\ \
| * | 150101f add majority of code
* | |   86708bf Merge branch 'master' of ui
|\ \ \
| |/ /
| | /
| |/
|/|
| *   8643023 (origin/master, origin/HEAD) added feature
| |\
```

Comment: What does the commit graph for just the `feature` branch look like? For that matter, what about the other 1 or 2 branches that you attempted to merge? I can see at least 2 or 3.

Comment: Also, it would be really great if you could show us the commands that you already tried, that got you your current commit graph.

Answer (score 0):

This part of your graph:

```
* |   0951849 Merge feature branch
|\ \
| * | 150101f add majority of code
* | |   86708bf Merge branch 'master' of ui
|\ \ \
| |/ /
| | /
| |/
|/|
| *   8643023 (origin/master, origin/HEAD) added feature
```

Looks like you tried to merge in a feature branch with just one commit, `150101f`, is that true? If so, you can start by rebasing or cherry-picking that commit onto `origin/master`. As long as there are no conflicts, you can re-order the rebased/cherry-picked commit with the other commits later:

```
git checkout -b linear-branch origin/master
git cherry-pick 150101f
```

I'll need more information about the other commits' graphs before I can help you figure out how to rebase/cherry-pick the rest.